# Compile LESS in Node.js & React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, less

Is there a way to automatically compile LESS in React.js?

I've installed it [according to the docs](http://lesscss.org/)

I know it's possible to use the `lessc` command, but it seems tedious to run that command manually everytime the less is updated.

I've tried this one too, but it doesn't work:

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

var less = require('less');
var lessCss = require('./app.less');

console.log(lessCss); //output: /static/media/app.725ced4d.less

less.render(lessCss, function (e, output) {
    console.log(e); //output: Unrecognized Input
    console.log(output); //output: undefined
});

class Main extends Component {
    /* render functions */
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native comes with everything you need already, i would suggest not using LESS but the preferred way from the official docs:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainView: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    ...
});
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html

Comment: I'm not using any webpack whatsoever, I think.. I created the example app using the given command. And modified that project.

Comment: what command exactly? what´s in the resulting package.json? how do you run the app?

Comment: ...if it´s create-react-app, then you are definitely using webpack and babel already.

Comment: ah, my bad. react native has everything packed together already. i will update my answer.